# Extracting minor version number from C# source using MSDOS batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008, jenkins, parsing

I need to extract the version number from this C# source line using MSDOS batch file:

```
public const int major_version = 2;
```

My attempt:

```
::  Extract the number-token from the major version string.
::  The number-token has a semicolon appended.
for /F "tokens=6" %%a in ( str_Major_REV) do set number_token=%%a
```

This results in the variable `number_token` as `2;`.

How can I remove the `';'`?
*{The `';'` is used as a line separator by the `delims` parameter.}*

**Background:**
The batch file is run by Jenkins build server.  I want the batch file to:

1. Extract the number.
2. Increment the number and save as environment / batch file variable.
3. Replace the original number with the incremented number.
4. Use the number in a folder name.
5. Use the number in a Code Management System version/label.

Items 4 and 5 are reasons I need the semicolon removed from the number token.

**Environment**
Windows server 2008

Comment: (1) `delims` containing semicolon works fine for me on Vista, which should be the same as 2008, and is not a 'line separator' (2) To remove the last character `%number_token:~0,-1%` (3) To remove semicolon anywhere `%number_token:;=%`

Comment: A much easier way is a for loop `for %%A in (%str_Major_Rev%) do @set "number_token=%%A"` Space, semocolon, comma, tab are all argument seperators. The loop wil set all items, but the last will stay.